# Ansible under GPLv3: can you redistribute it without open-sourcing the rest of my solution?

Tags: gpl-3

Assuming I am building a solution that leverages [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) to set up an environment for my application to live. If I package my solution in a server image that contains Ansible:

Will the use of Ansible as a tool (assuming it's packaged in the server image I distribute) considered as using it as a "library" and would it require me to open source my whole solution?

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#MereAggregation ?

Comment: I had not! What I understand is that it would be permissible because it's considered as part of an aggregate and not tightly coupled?

Comment: I do not know Ansible, I can't say how closely it is tied to the other parts. You will have to do your own assessment of the facts and act accordingly.

Comment: In our case we would be passing data as command line arguments which alligns with the last option - amazing man, thanks for this!

Answer (score 4):

No, using Ansible as a tool or library in your solution would not require you to open source your whole solution. Ansible is licensed under the GPLv3, which is a copyleft license that requires you to share the source code of any modifications or derivatives of the Ansible codebase that you distribute. However, this does not mean that you need to open source your entire solution.

- If you distribute a server image that includes Ansible, you would only need to share the modified source code of Ansible itself (if any modifications were made).
- If your solution includes any scripts or playbooks that are specific to your application and are not part of the Ansible codebase, those scripts may need to be released under an open source license compatible with the GPLv3.